# android app crach when clicking alertdialog.show two times

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Slam .

I am trying to show view inside alertDialog, every thing goes fine and the view popup without any problem, but when i click show view again the application crash and bring this error

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Comment: post your code and error stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slam again
the error was in showing the same view again, 
i solve it by creating new alertDian everytime i click show view

```
customerDetails = new AlertDialog.Builder(OrderDetails.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_details, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reusing the same view for the alert dialog.  Either don't do that (create a new one), or you must remove it from the previous dialog.  Making a new one is likely easier.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes up when opening the dialog for the second time, right? You're trying to re-use the same view with the alert dialog which is why you're seeing this error.

You can either completely remove the view before re-inflating the dialog, by calling `removeView()` as written in the error message. Or just inflate the view again, which is what is normally done. You want the view to live and die with the dialog. To do this, you should `inflater.inflate(...)` the view alongside your dialog creation code.

If you post your code, we can help you further.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by creating the separate layout xml file with the Edit Text. After that I did :

```
//alert_edit_text is the edit text id which is in separate file
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
val inflater = layoutInflater
val dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_edit_text, null)
val editText = dialogLayout.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edit_text_alert)
```

After your certain code,

```
setView(dialogLayout)
show()
```